# could i use for loop ? or function for this and make is shortest and dinamic for this array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, expression

I am new and want to learn here, so I want to get some information and study from you'all.
Could we use ForEach for this or an if statement??

```js
    var people = [
      [1, 'Dimitri', 'Microsoft'],
      [2, 'Mike', 'Microsoft'],
      [3, 'John', 'Microsoft']
    ];
    
    
    var people2 = `ID : ${people[0][0]}`;
    var people3 = `NAME : ${people[0][1]}`;
    var people4 = `COMPANY : ${people[0][2]}`;
    console.log(people2);
    console.log(people3);
    console.log(people4);
    
    var people5  = `ID : ${people[1][0]}`;
    var people6 = `NAME : ${people[1][1]}`;
    var people7 = `COMPANY : ${people[1][2]}`;
    console.log(people5);
    console.log(people6);
    console.log(people7);
    
    var people8  = `ID : ${people[2][0]}`;
    var people9 = `NAME : ${people[2][1]}`;
    var people10 = `COMPANY : ${people[2][2]}`;
    console.log(people8);
    console.log(people9);
    console.log(people10);
```

Comment: what do you like to get?

Comment: i have tried but i i am not sure, and syntax always error

Comment: Then post the code you have tried and include the **textual content of the error**.  Your question is basically, "can I use loops" and the answer is "Yes", but we can't help you figure out your error until you post concrete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldm use an array for the wanted description and take the values of the array of the corresponding index.

```js
var people = [[1, 'Dimitri', 'Microsoft'], [2, 'Mike', 'Microsoft'], [3, 'John', 'Microsoft']],
    keys = ['ID', 'NAME', 'COMPANY'];

people.forEach(a => keys.forEach((k, i) => console.log(`${k} : ${a[i]}`)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you like to get objects with names properties, you could use [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

```js
var people = [[1, 'Dimitri', 'Microsoft'], [2, 'Mike', 'Microsoft'], [3, 'John', 'Microsoft']];

console.log(people.map(([ID, NAME, COMPANY]) => ({ ID, NAME, COMPANY })));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Since the array is hard-coded, it could be an array of objects to begin with rather than using `map()` to create the array of objects.

Comment: ID: 1
Name: Dimitri
Company: Microsoft

the output is still be array and object, could i get it like the output on above @nina

Comment: @iLnx, where do you want to get the output?

Comment: @iLnx Do you mean with each value on a separate line?

Comment: yes @Code-Apprentice
id: 1<br>
name: Dimitri <br>
company : Microsoft

Comment: d: 1<br> name: Dimitri <br> company : Microsoft @nina

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner you can simply use `For loop` to iterate 2D array.For desired output you can keep `keys` in a separate array and print as **description** .

```js
var people = [
  [1, 'Dimitri', 'Microsoft'],
  [2, 'Mike', 'Microsoft'],
  [3, 'John', 'Microsoft']
];
var keys = ["ID","NAME","COMPANY"];
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    var peopeleData = people[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < peopeleData.length; j++) {
        //console.log("people[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + peopeleData[j]);
         console.log(keys[j]+" : "+ peopeleData[j]);
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 10; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an array, you should definitely use a loop to iterate over it. In this case, you should create an array of objects instead of an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can:

```js
 var people = [
    [1, 'Dimitri', 'Microsoft'],
    [2, 'Mike', 'Microsoft'],
    [3, 'John', 'Microsoft']
];
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    var item = people[i];
    for (var s = 0; s < item.length; s++) {
        var subitem = item[s];
        switch (s) {
            case 0: console.log('ID :' + subitem); break;
            case 1: console.log('NAME :' + subitem); break;
            case 2: console.log('COMPANY :' + subitem); break;
        }
    }
}
```

But use a json array for next time. Greetings

```html
  var people = [
        { 'ID': 1, 'NAME': 'Dimitri', 'COMPANY': 'Microsoft' },
        { 'ID': 2, 'NAME': 'Mike', 'COMPANY': 'Microsoft' },
        { 'ID': 3, 'NAME': 'John', 'COMPANY': 'Microsoft' }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the structure of people to an array of objects instead like this :

```
var people = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Dimitri', company: 'Microsoft' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mike', company: 'Microsoft' },
  { id: 3, name: 'John', company: 'Microsoft' },
];
```

And then use it with any loop you want using destructuring. Examples :

```js
var people = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Dimitri', company: 'Microsoft' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mike', company: 'Microsoft' },
  { id: 3, name: 'John', company: 'Microsoft' },
];

// Using for loop
console.log( 'for loop' );
for ( let i = 0; i < people.length; i++ )
{
  const { id, name, company } = people[ i ];
  
  // Do something with id, name and company
  console.log( id, name, company );
}

// Using for each
console.log( 'for each' );
people.forEach( ({ id, name, company }) => {

  // Do something with id, name and company
  console.log( id, name, company );
  
});

// Using for of
console.log( 'for of' );
for ( const { id, name, company } of people )
{
  // Do something with id, name and company
  console.log( id, name, company );
}
```

If you wish to have more information about desctructuring you can refer to Mozilla docs online at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment